# Microsoft Outlook 2003: Multiple POP3 account trouble

Tags: email, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2003, pop3

I just created a new POP3 account in my 2003 Outlook. I checked the settings and the Inbox-Outbox are working well.

However if I send from my standard Outlook POP3 account a mail to my second one, I do not receive it.

I receive the message:

```
550-Mailbox unknown.  Either there is no mailbox associated with this
550-name or you do not have authorization to see it. 550 5.1.1 User unknown
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The error message already tells you the problem - you do not have access to the mailbox.

Possible causes:

- You mistyped your login name.
- You have been denied access by the administrator (or by an evil mailserver).